# Why do JRBeanCollectionDataSource give null fields passing List, using jr:list component?

Tags: java, arraylist, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am creating a jasper report which contain the header and a list of elements. I am passing the array list of custom object through `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` to jasper report i have used list component. But it is returning the null fields always though i have data in list.

Here is my bean class:

```
public class Medicine {

    private String medicineName;
    private String schedule;
    private String date;
    private String hour;
    private String dosage;
    private String taken;

    public String getMedicineName() {
        return medicineName;
    }
    public void setMedicineName(String medicineName) {
        this.medicineName = medicineName;
    }
    public String getSchedule() {
        return schedule;
    }
    public void setSchedule(String schedule) {
        this.schedule = schedule;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getHour() {
        return hour;
    }
    public void setHour(String hour) {
        this.hour = hour;
    }
    public String getDosage() {
        return dosage;
    }
    public void setDosage(String dosage) {
        this.dosage = dosage;
    }
    public String getTaken() {
        return taken;
    }
    public void setTaken(String taken) {
        this.taken = taken;
    }

}
```

This is how i am sending data to report.

```
try {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("reports/medipost.jrxml").getFile());
           JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                   .compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());
           MediPostDAO mediPostDAO = new MediPostDAO();
           Map<String, Object> parameters = mediPostDAO.getMedipostData(id);
           List<Medicine> medicineList = new MedicineDAO().getMedicineList(id);
           JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(medicineList);
           JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
                   parameters, ds);

           try {
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, response.getOutputStream());
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And this is a jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.2.1.final using     JasperReports Library version 6.2.1  -->
<!-- 2016-04-20T18:08:25 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2e9583be-f081-46a8-ab4f-06825850ee37">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<style name="Table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
    </box>
</style>
<subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="de015a45-b31b-4e76-b602-c48d2099b2f0">
    <parameter name="medicineName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="schedule" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="hour" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="dosage" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Taken" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="date" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="medicineName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dosage" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="hour" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="taken" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="schedule" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>
<parameter name="disease" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="doctor" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="pharmacy" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="symptom" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="profileName" class="java.lang.String">
    <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
</parameter>
<parameter name="age" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="gender" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="bloodGroup" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="101">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="180" height="20" uuid="38b835c7-7f37-4208-9e17-f1265afe7abd"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="16" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{profileName}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="35" width="30" height="20" uuid="9c9ddeee-18b9-4d0c-aad9-32e8e00d375a"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Age]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="30" y="36" width="17" height="19" uuid="35a16a58-bef5-4753-a3a6-5478eeda8aac"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="51" y="35" width="1" height="20" uuid="7962e3e8-0f3d-4096-8145-569d5044f401">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="55" y="35" width="50" height="20" uuid="2d568652-4551-40b8-9a0f-b504cced79d5"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Gender]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="102" y="35" width="46" height="20" uuid="1755ba6d-a486-4adf-83da-1a06af7c1369"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{gender}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="150" y="35" width="1" height="20" uuid="6371ec0f-d26f-4e82-88ec-26a724c40d54">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="150" y="36" width="80" height="20" uuid="5634ce23-b218-4ffe-8237-cc49ceeea862"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Blood Group]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="230" y="36" width="51" height="21" uuid="45df73f2-4a33-47e9-8d0b-804c99946bcc"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{bloodGroup}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="-5" y="57" width="63" height="20" uuid="ea748f7d-f4d0-4e9e-8379-a52e74b0cbf2"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Condition]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="52" y="57" width="90" height="20" forecolor="#F51511" uuid="ae53e0e0-d755-4cfd-9e7a-b3bbde881f9d"/>
            <box>
                <topPen lineColor="#F22824"/>
                <leftPen lineColor="#F22824"/>
                <bottomPen lineColor="#F22824"/>
                <rightPen lineColor="#F22824"/>
            </box>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="none">
                <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{disease}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="140" y="55" width="1" height="20" uuid="1f89c71f-d8a3-4dee-9943-417470344334">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="142" y="57" width="63" height="20" uuid="e887596a-a3b6-4285-afca-4d96b9c27f64"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Symptoms]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="57" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#F21511" uuid="3ba4e883-6b4e-44a8-8360-b1acff38e3d9"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{symptom}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="300" y="57" width="1" height="20" uuid="3a76da0b-a958-4dee-bb9a-560098b496d6">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="301" y="57" width="63" height="20" uuid="5fcd5ba3-a11a-45e3-9e22-56b272211390"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <text><![CDATA[Doctors]]></text>
        </staticText>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="360" y="57" width="100" height="21" forecolor="#FA1D19" uuid="a9f3ff9e-74b8-4112-b1c1-cdca8bd918b3"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="12" isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{doctor}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="-3" y="85" width="560" height="1" uuid="489b1135-0cd0-4d47-8ed4-6a689582c264">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="281" height="1" uuid="f16072f4-ed14-410c-a6fd-2851b2f88f04">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
        <line>
            <reportElement x="0" y="31" width="560" height="1" uuid="d515cf7a-05b5-4a5e-b30c-95b8e79f2381">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            </reportElement>
        </line>
    </band>
</pageHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="33832d43-6539-48db-ae31-fc5836c7f038">
                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.HorizontalRowLayout"/>
            </reportElement>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="b8e46627-a532-4836-bcb1-56f47d997ef9">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource() ]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="30" width="100">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="20" height="30" uuid="7985e712-7deb-4f22-869f-2f2ebcd77f59"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="20" y="0" width="16" height="30" uuid="0b0ede12-bd96-46ba-afd8-41581438b6a4"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{medicineName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="36" y="0" width="16" height="30" uuid="5c597083-edf0-4159-b455-018f9b83f8ee"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{dosage}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="52" y="0" width="16" height="30" uuid="483a1dc0-d6a5-40e6-8e51-ca03cde8a7b1"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{hour}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="68" y="0" width="16" height="30" uuid="2bdf851b-2981-40a2-b3fd-42bd8df3b990"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{taken}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="84" y="0" width="16" height="30" uuid="cf0cf0e7-ec90-42d4-ba3f-fb27563890fe"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{schedule}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Are you still having issue with this?

Answer (score 1):

This is becasue you are using a **subdatset** for your list component while passing the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` to the main report. Hence the main report has the `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` but your list component has an `JREmptyDataSource`

**A solution**

- Pass the List as a parameter

  ```
  parameter.put("medicineList",new MedicineDAO().getMedicineList(id));
  ```
- Pass an [JREmptyDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JREmptyDataSource.html) to the report (you are **not** using this datasource, pass 1 record to display the detail band once)

  ```
  JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
             parameters, new JREmptyDataSource(1))
  ```
- Add the new parameter to your jrxml and pass a correct datasource to your `jr:list`

  ```
  <parameter name="medicineList" class="java.util.List" isForPrompting="false"/>
  ....
  <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="b8e46627-a532-4836-bcb1-56f47d997ef9">
        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{medicineList}) ]]></dataSourceExpression>
    </datasetRun>
  ....
  ```

Furthermore, you are having the same confusion with the parameters, parameter used in main report (not inside of list component) needs to be define at main report level (not inside subdatset), parameter used in component it is correct to define them inside subdatset but you need also to pass them to the component.